# Using JAXB in constructor

Tags: java, constructor, jaxb, factory

Currently I have a factory method to create RndObj from XML

```
    public static RndObj loadRndObjFromXMLFile(String xmlFile) {
        RndObj ro = null;
        try {
            JAXBContext context = JAXBContext.newInstance(RndObj.class);
            Unmarshaller unmarshaller = context.createUnmarshaller();
            File file = new File(xmlFile);
            ro = (RndObj) unmarshaller.unmarshal(file);
        } catch (JAXBException e) {
        }
```

However I would prefer to have just a constructor in RndObj like this

```
    public RndObj(String xmlFile) {
        //this = Factory.loadRndObjFromXMLFile(xmlFile);--------- would be nice
        RndObj ro = Factory.loadRndObjFromXMLFile(xmlFile);
        this.attribute1 = ma.getAttribute1();
        this.attribute2 = ma.getAttribute2();
        this.attribute3 = ma.getAttribute3();
        this.attribute4 = ma.getAttribute4();
        this.attribute5 = ma.getAttribute5();
        this.attribute6 = ma.getAttribute6();
    }
```

It works but:
there are tons of attributes and fields I need to copy and it kinda sucks that I create two objects and then copy from one to another. Plus there might be new field once in a while and I always have to keep track that this constructor is up2date.

Is there a better way to achieve what I am trying?

Answer (score 0):

Depends a bit on your restrictions and the complexity of your data classes.

One easy option would be to not use a constructor but a static method.
Something like:

```
public class RndObj{
   // other stuff
   static RndObj load(String xmlFile){
        return Factory.loadRndObjFromXMLFile(xmlFile);
   }
}
```

Another option would be the library BeanUtils:

```
public RndObj(String xmlFile) {
    //this = Factory.loadRndObjFromXMLFile(xmlFile);--------- would be nice
    RndObj ro = Factory.loadRndObjFromXMLFile(xmlFile);
    BeanUtils.copyProperties(ro, this);
}
```

not ideal to leak `this` in a constructor. If the classes is only a datacontainer that should be fine.